# How to force a refresh in Next.js 13 and reload data from database?

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to build a subscription based web application using Next.js 13, and letting users manually end their Free Trial to begin a Premium subscription, which is displayed as the user's current plan client-side.

When the user hits a button calling confirmPlanStart, the backend updates correctly (e.g., subscription plan is updated from "Free Trial" to "Premium"), but my client side doesn't automatically re-render as I want it to.

When I manually hit refresh, the client side correctly re-renders to show "Premium" instead of "Free Trial".

I've tried using window.location.reload() and router.refresh(), but it's still not refreshing the client side correctly.

There must be something I'm not understanding properly about Next.js reloading, would appreciate any help!

Sharing code below:

```js
const confirmPlanStart = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/confirmPlanStart", { method: "POST" });
      toast.success(
        "Success! You have been billed and your paid plan has begun."
      );
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(
        "Something went wrong, try again later or contact support@domain.com for help."
      );
    } finally {
      console.log("finally block")
      window.location.href = "/settings";
      router.refresh(); // have also tried window.location.reload()
    }
  };
```

This is in a client component if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Components in the client-side are automatically re-rendered when its state changes.

Use this hook [useState](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) to add a state to your component that flips its value everytime you get a response from the server. This state change will force a re-render.

As an example you can do this:

```js
const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

const confirmPlanStart = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/confirmPlanStart", { method: "POST" });
      toast.success(
        "Success! You have been billed and your paid plan has begun."
      );
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(
        "Something went wrong, try again later or contact support@domain.com for help."
      );
    } finally {
      console.log("finally block")
      window.location.href = "/settings";
      setRefresh(!refresh); // This forces a re-render
    }
  };
```

Alternatively, you can also have a more meaningful state that can hold the status of your response instead of just a boolean that flips to force a re-render.

Comment: Got it, would it just re-render this component or would it refresh the entire page? I'm looking for something to refresh the page and all the displayed components

Comment: It will re-render just this component. For the entire page reload, try the simpler approach of using router.reload() from `import { useRouter } from "next/router";` but if that does not work you may need to reload all displayed components by linking all components so that this state change will change the state (or props) of the other components in that page.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use router.refresh() which is immported from "next/navigate" or use built-in function "invalidatePath/Tag". With 2nd option, makes sure structure your fetch well.